# overflow hidden is not working, my header is overwritten by content

Tags: html, css, styles, overflow, hidden

I'm creating a website but I have a problem, when I create a header with position: fixed, the header that I make is positioned under the content and the header I make is stacked and I also use overflow: hidden but the content is still over the header

this is my website: https://zoomcoding.id/members/santriwibs/tes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

Overlapping issue

**SOLUTION**

use `z-index` CSS property on `header` element

e.g

```
#header {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)